# Google OpenID: Don't log in to gmail

Tags: google-api, openid

My website is primarily used by students on shared laptops and computers in school. They have Google Apps for Education accounts which they use to log in to my site through OpenID. I have the login authentication working, and by passing the `openid.pape.max_auth_age` parameter = 0 I can force users to log in every time they hit the "Login with Google" button regardless of if there is a currently logged in google user or not. After Google has verified the user's email address, I find the associated user in my database and log them in.

The problem is, I can't find a way to prevent google from logging the user in to all of their google applications at the same time that they log in to mine via openid. When a user logs off of my site, unless I manually trigger a full google logout by making a GET request to https://accounts.google.com/Logout (which feels unstable and hacky, and is not the expected behavior of my site), the user remains logged in to gmail. The next student who goes to gmail.com on that computer will have access to all of the previous user's information.

Is there a way to tell google not to fully log in a user when they use OpenID on my site?

Comment: That's not really up to you. It's the way Google handles their OpenID login mechanism. You could use a different login mechanism, or go with the redirect to .../Logout.